# Hibernate: getting a record but it's being updated in the database?

Tags: java, hibernate

For some reason Hibernate seems to be keeping my session open and updating the object without me explicitely invoking a save/update/saveorupdate. I guess the session is staying open and it's beeing marked as dirty.

However this is not the desired behaviour, so what's the cleanest way to fix this?

The issue seems to occur because I store a phone number without formatting in the database but the getter of the object returns a formatted telephone number.

My flow:
go to a jsp => controller => service => dao

DAO getter function

```
if(userId != 0) {
   return (User)dbFactory.get(User.class, userId);
}
return null;
```

The service just passes it to the controller and the controller puts te User object in the request scope. I display it on my JSP page using EL.

edit:
I added the following:
JSP:

```
<spring:bind path = "user.telephoneNumber">${user.telephoneNumber}</spring:bind>
```

Controller:

```
@InitBinder
    public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.registerCustomEditor(String.class, "telephoneNumber", new TelephoneNumberEditor(false));
    }
```

The editor:
public class TelephoneNumberEditor extends PropertyEditorSupport {
    private boolean isRequired = false;

```
public TelephoneNumberEditor(boolean isRequired) {
    this.isRequired = isRequired;
}

public void setAsText(String text) throws IllegalArgumentException {
   String s = null;
    if (!this.isRequired && StringUtils.isBlank(text)) {
        setValue("");
    }
    else
    {
        s = text.replace("(0)","");
        s = s.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");
        setValue(s);
    }
}

public String getAsText() {
    String telephoneNumber = (String) getValue();
    if(StringUtils.isBlank(telephoneNumber)){
        return "";
    } else {
        try {
            MaskFormatter formatter = new MaskFormatter("+AA AA AA AA AA");
            formatter.setValueContainsLiteralCharacters(false);
            return formatter.valueToString(telephoneNumber);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            return "";
        }
    }
}
```

}

And in the controller I put the User object in the request scope as user.

Comment: I would look for some odd property being set in hibernate.cfg or persistence.xml. or just post those as well as your sping.xml

Answer (score 1):

You can create another property (getter and setter) for the formatted value and mark it as transient (with `@Transient` or by omitting it in your `.hbm.xml`):

```
@Transient
public String getFormattedPhoneNumber() { ... }
public void setFormattedPhoneNumber(String number) { ... }
```

Alternatively, you can configure Hibernate access type to work with fields instead of properties - in that case your getters can return arbitrary representations.

**EDIT:** If you use Spring MVC databinding, you can implement your formatting logic in `PropertyEditor`. Since formatting a phone number is a presentation concern, moving it to the presentation layer looks reasonable:

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.registerCustomEditor(String.class, "phoneNumber", 
        new PropertyEditorSupport() { ... });
}
```

In this approach custom editor works automatically in the typical Spring from processing cycle (form is rendered with [Spring form tags](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/view.html#view-jsp-formtaglib) and data are bound to `@ModelAttribute` upon POST). If you need to display formatted value manually (outside of form tags), you can use [`<spring:bind>`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/spring.tld.html):

```
<spring:bind path = "user.phoneNumber">${status.displayValue}</spring:bind>
```

(or without `user.` if inside `<form:form>`, I guess)

Comment: Option one isn't an option for me since I use spring binding to bind it to an input field so the getter and setter must match. But the second one is an option.

Comment: @jack: Updated. By the first option I mean implementing a getter/setter pair. However, if you use Spring MVC, you can move your formatting logic into `PropertyEditor` and keep your entity more clean.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I wrote a custom editor for it but it does not seem to be invoked. I put a User object as user in the request but when I do ${user.phoneNumber} it shows the nonformated version.

Comment: @axtavt I tried your approach and the formatting isn't applied. I'll update my startpost with what I did since I can use formatting there.

Comment: I tried a system.errror.println in the editor and that doesn't show in my console either. So it seems like it isn't being invoked.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make non-persistent changes to a persistent object you can explicitly kick it out of context with `Session.evict(Object object)`.  Hibernate will not persist any changes you make to it after that's done.

Something about the description of why it happens doesn't quite add up.  Are you using property based access for persistence, and not using direct getters-setters?  A getter that marks up the value might raise architectural objections but in and of itself shouldn't be causing persistence problems.

Comment: I'm using Expression Language to display the information so the getter is invoked. ${user.telephoneNumber}  The reason that the formatting is done in the getter and not in the JSP itself is that the formatting depends on the phone number. There are 3 different ways I need to format the number and that's a bit too much logic in a jsp for my liking.